# Removing a value from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove a value within the Firebase Realtime Database. Here is the code I am using:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference()
           .child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("instagramLink")
           .removeValue()
```

Here is the JSON Data Structure:

```
Users {

    userUID {

        email: "test@test.com"
        fullName: "John Doe"
        instagramLink: "testLink"
    }
}
```

I am telling the database to remove the key "instagramLink", which I know is currently in the database, but the key never gets removed.

How do I remove the key?

Comment: What does your data structure look like? Please add an example of the JSON you're trying to modify (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: Just added it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extending to @cartant's answer , this way you will know if you run along any error during removal or if the value's were removed successfully or not.:)

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(Users).child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("instagramLink").removeValueWithCompletionBlock({ (error, refer) in
if error != nil {
 print(error)
   } else {
  print(refer)
 print("Child Removed Correctly")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you've left `Users` out of the path:

```
FIRDatabase.database()
    .child("Users")
    .child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
    .child("instagramLink")
    .removeValue()
```